# Issue with jquery select all option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here which i need in order to make possible multiple selection.
Now, at the moment is optionally, you chose for it to be single selection or multiple selection, like the code below:

```
<span>Selection Mode: </span>
<select onchange="$('#dg').datagrid({singleSelect:(this.value==1)})">
<option value="0">Single Row</option>
<option value="1">Multiple Rows</option>
</select><br/>
SelectOnCheck: <input type="checkbox" checked onchange="$('#dg').datagrid({selectOnCheck:$(this).is(':checked')})"><br/>
CheckOnSelect: <input type="checkbox" checked onchange="$('#dg').datagrid({checkOnSelect:$(this).is(':checked')})">
```

What can i do in order to make it always multiple selectable?
Thanks..

Comment: is `datagrid` a jquery plugin? Would be helpful to mention/link this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all that. In the page's javascript file, or in an embeded `<script>` block write:

```
$('#dg').datagrid({singleSelect:false});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, please i get an error in the line, could you take a look?

Comment: Opps! I'd left an extra paren in there.